# Как написать дробное число в python в нормальной форме?

Tags: python, типы-данных, float

Если в числе с плавающей точкой больше 3-х чисел после коммы, то число записывается с буквой e, а мне нужна обычная форма.
Допустим что бы 0.000000000 записалось как 0.00000000, а не 1e-08.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант:

```
value = 1e-5

print(f'{value:.10f}')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое